# Visual studio "inconsistent line endings"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to VS, never really used it much. Prefer other IDE's but when it's a toss up between VS and MonoDevelop, I was told VS was the better choice.

I set it as my default editor in Unity and it's giving me this message every so often

**The line endings in this file are not consistent. Do you want to normalize the endings?**

Then it gives me a list such as

**Windows (CR LF)**
**Macintosh (CR)**
**Unix (LF)**

How can I stop this from coming up?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can turn off that check in **Tools/Options/Environment/Documents**

Uncheck "**Check for consistent line endings on load**"

[image: Line endings check]

Comment: This looks more like ignoring the problem, rather than solving it. :( what is causing this problem? Is it a bug in Unity or in VS? How comes that I'm programming on Windows with programs made for Windows and they still got to have mixed line endings types?

Comment: It's difficult to answer that without knowing more about this particular case, but one possible cause can be if a file is edited by multiple people with different OSes, since the line endings are encoded by different character sequences on different OSes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I stumbled upon this question because I have a similar problem. In my case, I'm working all by myself on this project, on windows, but the same files are managed both by Unity and by Visual Studio. It seems like for some reason, they treat the files in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to cover up by changing the document setting, you can try and remediate by replacing the faulty line endings. See post '[how to fix inconsistent line endings for whole vs solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294779/how-to-fix-inconsistent-line-endings-for-whole-vs-solution).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GitHub to store your code, this is likely caused by it replacing all of your line endings on commit, which VS doesn't like.

To fix this, open the ".gitattributes" file which should be in your solution folder and change the line `* text=auto` to `#* text=auto`, which will comment it out, disabling that behaviour.

More info: [What is the purpose of `text=auto` in `.gitattributes` file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472971/what-is-the-purpose-of-text-auto-in-gitattributes-file)