# Is that necessary for checking "inconsistency of line endings" VS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, editor, end-of-line

I am using VS 2017 on only Windows. However, it frequently pops up the warning
**“inconsistent line endings”**.

I found a solution to turn it off from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35104471/visual-studio-inconsistent-line-endings). But then I have some questions related to this issue:

1. I use only Windows, why does it have such inconsistency?
2. If we can turn this off then is it any benefit of enabling it?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

In particular these 3 sections:

- [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode)
- [In programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages)
- [Frequent issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Frequent_issues)

The inconsistencies generally come from: copy-pasted code, snippets, using different editors/environments or through a file transfer protocol (or code repository).

As for the benefit: it can cause issues where the content is either not displayed in a human-readable fashion or the content is misinterpreted by a process (i.e. compiler).