# Importing a CSV file with accent marks

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-csv

I have a excel file (.XLSX/.CSV/UTF-8) etc with 1390 lines however I am getting an issue with CSVLint stating that I have `inconsistent line breaks` I note in the spreadsheet it is using a lot of accents on words punctuation marks etc.

How could I alter this file so it will be valid and import correctly?

Comment: XLSX and CSV are two completely different files. I can't find doc explaining "inconsistent line breaks" but I guess it means there are a mix of CRLF and just CR

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thats what it is - I am looking for a way to straighten them all out as CRLF

Comment: Use as RegEx Find/Replace tool to replace CR^[LF] with CRLF. You'll also need a capture in the regex to not overwrite whatever follows CR. What are your options for running an external tool / script?

Comment: Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294779/how-to-fix-inconsistent-line-endings-for-whole-vs-solution

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Can you run me through how to do this plz, No options open to anything :)

Comment: I have no idea what you can and can't do. Try googling "fix inconsistent line endings" and find a solution that appeals to you. For example are you happy with a manual process?